# Is there a downside to declaring a pointer used for allocated memory as const

Tags: c, pointers

It struck me that if I declare a chunk of memory using a const pointer, like so:

```c
SomeType * const pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer);
```

I can't accidentally "lose" the pointer, (i.e. by modifying it or overwriting it).  This seems like a convenient "reminder" that the memory it's pointing to needs to be freed.  Is there a downside to doing this?  A number of things come to mind, perhaps due to returning the pointer from a function, or because it may be incompatible with a large number of library functions.  However these seem like inconveniences rather than an actual error.

Comment: What do you mean with "returning the pointer from a function"? You can return an address from a function, but had to assign that to a pointer variable in the caller, which - if you declare that `const` cannot be changed after initialisation. Which you already noticed. So?

Comment: @Olaf I don't know, that's why I'm asking.  Would doing that cause issues?

Comment: If it's const, you won't be able to resize with `realloc()`

Comment: I don't see your problem. Maybe you have some missconception about how parameters and function results are passed. C ist strictly pass-by-value, so what influence should library functions have?

Comment: @Dmitri: That's wrong! You do not "allocate pointers" or "resize pointers", but the memory block they point **to**.

Comment: @olaf he's right.  You can't change the value of a const pointer once it's set.

Comment: @Olaf Obviously... but he'd still need a second pointer to access the resized block with in case the block was moved (in which case the original const one would become useless).  I didn't say the *pointer* was what was allocated...

Comment: @Tibrogargan: Please point me at where there is a requirement to use the same pointer for `realloc`! (Actually you never should overwrite the pointer valriable you passed before checking the result!) It is getting even less clear. You seem to understand `const` qualified variables cannot be changed after definition. But then you state the obvious: they cannot be changed. Maybe you first think over it and the implications?

Comment: @Dmitri: Somethink like `p = realloc(p, ..)` is doomed from the beginning anyway! **Never** use `malloc`, `realloc` etc. without checking the result before using it. And that line above is a good recipe to get a memory leak.

Comment: The only library functions I can fathom this would be "incompatible" with would be something that takes the pointer itself by address (pointer to pointer). Anything that takes a straight up pointer as a parameter will do so by-value, and as such the constness of the pointer var itself is irrelevant. Regardless, I'd find this generally useless, as most algorithms we use pointers for rely on the ability to *change* them, which pursuing this this prohibits. In short, sure, you can't "accidentally" overwrite your pointer, but neither can you *purposely*, which happens more than you seem to think.

Comment: @Olaf I can see no reason why this shouldn't be done, but I don't know everything about C, which is why I'm asking the question.  You seem to be under the impression that I should know everything already

Comment: @Olaf Of course you'd normally use a second pointer temporarily to facilitate error handling, but you'd normally end up assigning back to the original pointer afterwards -- it's often not practical to change the variable used to access the block after every resize.

Comment: @WhozCraig: A PtP function shall generate a warning anyway for such a pointer.

Comment: @Dmitri: I don't see where this leads. That's the **obvious** implication of using a `const` qualified variable. OP seems to have understood this concept. He does not seem to have understood the implications. To understand those, the best is to think it over. That's tutoring. And not what we are for.

Comment: @Olaf: true, but in case of success you overwrite the old pointer back, otherwise you may need infinitely many locals if you realloc in a loop.

Comment: @Olaf: you're assuming too much on behalf of the OP of what they know or want to know. They ask an obvious question so there is nothing non-obvious to expect in the answers.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I strongly disagree. It is not possible to give a comprehensive list of implications at the level OP asks. Having understood the basic, he should be able to deduce whether a specific usage is allowed or not. That is common and one of the most basic practices in programming. It simply is a vital skill of (not only) a programmer.

Comment: @Olaf how is it not possible?  You should be able to deduce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get it. You still can forget to `free` it.

On the downside you cannot set it to `0` after you freed it to indicate that it is already freed, so you may risk in calling `free` twice (think of some error handling code to imagine where it can happen).

**EDIT:** Additionally, as @Dmitri said in the comments, declaring the pointer `const` prevents you from reallocating it (by whatever means).

Comment: `free(NULL)` does nothing, you can free it as many times as you like.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: that's exactly my point. But you can't `free(pointer); pointer = NULL; free(pointer);` if it's declared `const`.

Comment: Setting a local pointer to `NULL` is often useless anyway. And static pointers to dynamic memory don't work anyway.

Comment: @ybungalobill why would you do that?

Comment: @Olaf: sometimes you `free` it early and zero it out, so in case of an error return (e.g. `goto` or `longjmp`) you can `free` it again.

Comment: He already wrote he wants that so he cannot change the pointer after initialisation. I think OP already understood **this** concept.

Comment: This seems to be the only downside.  Doesn't seem to make sense to use a defensive programming practice that's mutually exclusive with another one.  There might be a very small number of use cases where it would come in handy